# PHP Check if date is past in the format 10-08-2015

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the specific given date is past or not with PHP, I cannot change the date format as there are thousands of records like this in the database.

```
$actdate = '10-08-2015';
```

The format is day-month-year

Thank You

Edit: Get it working, thanks to Aruna Warnasooriya.

```
    $actdate = "10-08-2015";
    $yourdate = date_create(date($actdate));
    $mydate = $yourdate->format("Y-m-d");
    $date = new DateTime($mydate);
    $now = new DateTime();

    if($date < $now) {echo 'date is in the past';} else {echo 'date is not in the past'; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP :

```
$today = date("d-m-Y");
```

you can create a date using date_create function.This will create data object.

```
$actdate = "10-08-2015";
$yourdate = date_create(date($actdate));
```

format your date as you wish.like this;

```
echo $yourdate->format("d-m-Y");
```

Comment: Thanks I got it fixed. 

`$actdate = "10-08-2015";
$yourdate = date_create(date($actdate));
$mydate = $yourdate->format("Y-m-d");

$date = new DateTime($mydate);
$now = new DateTime();

if($date < $now) {
    echo 'date is in the past';
} else {echo 'date is not in the past'; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
 $today = date("d-m-Y");
    if ($actdate==$today){
    //date is today
    }else{
    //date not now
    }
```

Hope it what you want.